# Visual Studio: Set Project configuration 'Release' as default for new Solution configuration

Tags: visual-studio, solution, sln-file

I have a VS solution with **Release** and **Debug** Configuration. Each project in the solution has different settings for *Release* and *Debug*.

Now I have added a new solution configuration named 'DedicatedSolutionConfiguration'. With this configuration I will mark some projects not to be built.

I've changed the project configuration of each project in that solution configuration to 'Debug', because I like to use these project settings for that new solution configuration. That looks like this:
[image]

However, when I now add a new Project to the solution, the project's configuration inside the new configuration is initially always set to 'Debug':
[image]

Where can I change this behavior for the solution, that new added projects use 'Release' for the new solution configuration?

Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing further arround, I found out, how to set the 'default' project configuration for a new solution configuration for new projects in the solution.

When creating a new solution configuration, for *Copy settings from*, select the setting you want to keep also for new projects added to this solution and uncheck the *Create new project configurations*. Even you might think 'copy settings from' would only apply for the yet existing projects, it's also the default for every new added project!

[image]

Comment: This still does not work for any new project created.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set Configuration by default for example **Release**. You could configure it here:
[image]
[image]

After that when you creates new project it automatically set to selected configuration. Example of adding new project:
[image]

Comment: Just checked: Half the truth; This works with solution's 'Release' and 'Debug' configuration, but not with any self created solution configuration - for these it's always 'Debug' ...